# Insert Sharepoint list item is not working in Firefox

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, custom-list, firefox

I have created the visual web part and SharePoint custom list.and I used the angular js.The list item is not getting saved in Firefox.
save item code is:

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(SiteURL);
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(list);
        var oListItem = oList.getItemById($scope.SupportItemID);
        var Links = $(".jqte_editor").html()
        oListItem.set_item('Title', Title);
        oListItem.set_item('Overview', $scope.Overview);
        oListItem.set_item('PrimaryContactPhone', phone);
        oListItem.set_item('PrimaryContactEmail', Email);
        oListItem.set_item('HelpfulLinks', Links);
        oListItem.update();
        clientContext.load(oListItem);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryFailed));
        function onQuerySucceeded() {
        }
        function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
            alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
    }
```

Firefox issue is:

[image]

This is working fine in IE and Chrome.
suggest an idea to insert the list item in Firefox.

Comment: Do you get any error

Comment: I didn't get any error

Comment: if you donot find error and no updation happened, it seems it is not being called in firefox during function call.Add Console.log and check this function is being called or not

Comment: I have mentioned the error getting in firefox.it is not in IE and Chrome

Comment: It seems request fails in firefox, can you add more details of the error. It will be generally special charaters in the request

Comment: This is the only logged in console.I did not get any specefic errors in firefox.

Comment: issue is same as :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497567/issue-with-firefox-using-executequeryasync